# How to correctly redirect with inertia in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to redirect to another page with the click of a button, but for some reason it's not working, I'm not sure why?

Currently it opens up a window inside the main page not even a real redirect but it's blank. If I change the link to something else like just `"/"` or another page like `"/users"` then it works, but just for this link it's not working.

This is how I'm redirecting in the vue

```
<inertia-link href="imports/teachers">
    <el-button type="warning">Import</el-button>
</inertia-link>
```

In my web.php

```
Route::resource('imports/teachers', 'ImportTeacherController');
```

In the controller

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Import/Teacher');
}
```

In the teacher.vue I have a very basic layout

```
<template>
    <layout>
        <div>
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div>
    </layout>
</template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly redirect to another page with inertia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510606/correctly-redirect-to-another-page-with-inertia)

Answer (score 0):

`<inertia-link href="imports/teachers">` -> `<inertia-link href="/imports/teachers">`

You are missing a `/` before `imports`. It's just the same with normal anchor tags, you should add a leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You must make `<inertia-link href="/imports/teachers">`

There is also an even better solution which I always use. With this you can use routing names just have a look at it then it goes like this `<inertia-link href="route('import.teachers')">` https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Or you add it manually how it works you can find here: https://inertiajs.com/routing at `Generating URLs`.